# KeyError: 0 When using index to get value

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a website with Beautiful Soup. The `<tr>`s I search for contains several `<td>`s with the info I want.

I can run through the `<tr>`s with the "for column" line, but if I attempt to address the `<tr>` individually through their index with row[0], row[1], ... then it gives the "KeyError: 0" at that line.

Why can I run over the entries with a for loop but not address them with an index?

```
import bs4 as bs
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'cmc_main_table'})

# Make data usable
for row in table:
    print(row[0])
    for column in row:
        print(column)
        print("PING")
```

Comment: `row[0]` is error because `row` references only one `<tr>` inside the for-loop. For example `table[0]` will reference first row...

Comment: @AndrejKesely If I'm correct then each <tr> should house several <td>'s which I can run over with the for-loop but can't adress with row[0]

Furthermore I've commented out both for loops and tested the script with print(table[0]) which gives the same error.

Comment: `row.findAll('td')[0]` should give you first `<td>` inside the row.